# Why does Azure web app performance suffer so much when trying to delete a record that violates a foreign key constraint?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

Why does Azure web app performance suffer so much when trying to delete a record that violates a foreign key constraint?  I know, "Don't do that."  It just caught me by surprise that it could be such a huge factor.

I have an Azure website running about 125K requests/hour and it connects to Azure SQL S2 database with about 8GB throughput/day most of which is during normal business hours.  In the Azure portal charts, the website is normally about 40% CPU and 50% memory during the day.  The database averages about 15% CPU and 30 - 40% Data I/O and Log I/O.

I tried to delete a record using Mgt Studio that violated a foreign key constraint.  The website suffered greatly - the number of requests being handled dropped very low, CPU peaked, http queue length went very high, Autoscale added another instance, many http server errors started occurring and many clients were reporting timeouts and 502 bad gateway errors.

It took me a couple minutes to recognize the issue and cancel the query, canceling the query took another three minutes and it took 10-15 minutes for the web app to catch up.

My questions are, is this a normal response to a foreign key violation?  Do I have something structured wrong, either in the database or in the web service code that causes such an extended, disastrous effect from the foreign key violation error in Mgt. Studio?  Would upgrading to Azure Sql V12 eliminate this kind of issue?

Comment: How does SQL Server even allows for that? What happens if you perform this action locally?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was most likely a database performance issue.

The record I tried to delete is referenced by multiple foreign key constraints, most are delete cascade but one is not.

Most of the cascade delete references are for small numbers of records but one referenced 135,000 records in a table with a total of 600,000 records.

Another cascade delete may have referenced a small number of records in a table with few records but which may have a 10-15MB size blob in each them.  I don't know how much, if any, were referenced by the record I tried to delete.

I'm guessing it was performing the cascade deletes until it encountered the one table that didn't cascade delete and had to roll everything back.  In other words, the extended issues with the website were most likely because the database performance was suffering.  This aspect of Azure is disappointing.  When we were providing these services locally on a Windows Server 2003 virtual machine with Sql Server 2005 with several times more data, the database was much more responsive.  Perhaps an upgrade to Azure Sql V12 will help somewhat.